# Recode one column based off another

Tags: r, recode

Is there anyway to recode the data in one column based of a second column.

| Month | Treatment |
| --- | --- |
| June | A |
| May | A |
| May | B |
| June | B |
| May | C |
| June | C |

I have data for both may and june for different treatments as shown above.
I was recoding the treatment column as shown below.

```
Treat <- recode(Flower$Treatment, A = "Mown May and June")
Treat <- recode(Treat, B = "Mown May and June")
Treat <- recode(Treat, C = "Mown May")
```

however I would like to recode it so that the A, May is labelled Mown May and A, June is Mown  may and june. B, A is labelled Mown May and B, June is Mown  may and june. And C, May is labelled Mown May and C, June is labelled Not mown.

Is there anyway to do this using the recode function as I have already.

I would like the output to look like this:

| Month | Treatment | Treatment2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| June | A | Mown May and June |
| May | A | Mown May |
| May | B | Mown May |
| June | B | Mown May and June |
| May | C | No Mow May |
| June | C | Mown June |

Comment: Hello Rachel97, Welcome to StackOverflow! In order to get the answer you're looking for please update your post with the desired output (it could be as a table like the one in your post, but with the desired values added). There is quite some ambiguity between your post and your comments to @Basti's answer, which might limit the amount of answers you can get for your problem :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you are not restricted to `recode`, you could try to use `case_when()`, e.g.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Treatment2 = case_when(
    Month == "June" & Treatment %in% c("A", "B") ~ "Mown May and June",
    Month == "May" & Treatment %in% c("A", "B") ~ "Mown May",
    Month == "May" & Treatment == "C" ~ "No Mow May",
    TRUE ~ "Mown June"
  ))
```

**Result**:

```
  Month Treatment        Treatment2
1  June         A Mown May and June
2   May         A          Mown May
3   May         B          Mown May
4  June         B Mown May and June
5   May         C        No Mow May
6  June         C         Mown June
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, supposing df your dataframe and no other modalities of Treatment :

```
df$Treatment=ifelse(df$Month=="May","Mown May",
                    ifelse(df$Treatment=="C","Not mown","Mown May and June"))
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help but this didn't work quite as I hoped with some of the treatments being mislabeled. I was hoping the treatments would be labelled as No Mow May, Mown May, Mown in June, Not mown in June, Mown May and June and Not mown at all if that makes things any clearer

Comment: This is really different from what is written in your post, could you update your post and make recode guidelines clear for each variable combination? As it stands I do not know what is "Not Mown May". Thanks